# Need a formula that searches for a combination of values in a row and places the value in a cell depending on combination found

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to search for a set of possible values in a column to the left of said cell (actually, its three columns to the left), compare the combination with a list of end-result values and place a correct end result value in a cell. The values are contained within a list of values, separated with a comma. looks like this:

Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, ValueINeed1(out of possible 12) - ValueINeed1a(out of possible 3, but each possible value is unique to ValueINeed1), Value6, Value(n)

Right now, I'm using this formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H10) = TRUE;""; IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed1- SubValueINeed1a";H10; 1)); "Result1"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed1- SubValueINeed1b";H10; 1)); "Result2"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed1 - SubValueINeed1c";H10; 1)); "Result3"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed2 - ValueINeed2a";H10; 1)); "Result4"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed2 - ValueINeed2b";H10; 1)); "Result5"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed2 - ValueINeed2c";H10; 1)); "Result6"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed3 - ValueINeed3a";H10; 1)); "Result7"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed3 - ValueINeed3b";H10; 1)); "Result8"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed3 - ValueINeed3c";H10; 1)); "Result9"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed4 - ValueINeed4a";H10; 1)); "Result10"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed4 - ValueINeed4b";H10; 1)); "Result11"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed4 - ValueINeed4c";H10; 1)); "Result12"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed5 - ValueINeed5a";H10; 1)); "Result13"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed5 - ValueINeed5b";H10; 1)); "Result14"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed5 - ValueINeed5c";H10; 1)); "Result15"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed5 - ValueINeed5d";H10; 1)); "Result16"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed6 - ValueINeed6a";H10; 1)); "Result17"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed6 - ValueINeed6b";H10; 1)); "Result18"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed6 - ValueINeed6c";H10; 1)); "Result19"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed7 - ValueINeed7a";H10; 1)); "Result20"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed7 - ValueINeed7b";H10; 1)); "Result21"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed7 - ValueINeed7c";H10; 1)); "Result22"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed8 - ValueINeed8a";H10; 1)); "Result23"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed8 - ValueINeed8b";H10; 1)); "Result24"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed8 - ValueINeed8c";H10; 1)); "Result25"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed9 - ValueINeed9a";H10; 1)); "Result26"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed9 - ValueINeed9b";H10; 1)); "Result27"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed9 - ValueINeed9c";H10; 1)); "Result28"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed10 - ValueINeed10a";H10; 1)); "Result29";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed10 - ValueINeed10b";H10; 1)); "Result30"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed11 - ValueINeed11a";H10; 1)); "Result31"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed11 - ValueINeed11b";H10; 1)); "Result32"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed11 - ValueINeed11c";H10; 1)); "Result33"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed12 - ValueINeed12a";H10; 1)); "Result34"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed12 - ValueINeed12b";H10; 1)); "Result35"; IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ValueINeed12 - ValueINeed12c";H10; 1)); "Result36"; ""))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

ValueINeed5 has four corresponding "Subvalues", and ValueINeed10 - only two.

As you can see, this looks nasty, and I suspect it will murder my spreadsheet's performance as soon as the sheet grows several thousand rows long. Is there any solution I can use to replace this?

EDIT: 
Excuse me for my late reply.
Here's the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dpPY2h7jEQNdGj5USrdSu1Rhc_Dz1Ll0MyzvQwiVwM8/edit#gid=376650348
I've replaced the info I'm working with with for clarity's sake, and put a comment in each column's heading. Please feel free to comment the table.

Comment: Maybe vlookup() could help. Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet (sensitive data erased) so we have something to work with?

Comment: JPV, I'm not sure if it will. In each individual case, I'm looking specifically at the value that is contained in a cell in the same row